# Visual Studio 2015 C# Not finding references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have been having a problem with Visual Studio 2015 and C#. When adding reference to other projects in the same solution, Visual Studio is not finding all the classes. For example I created a unit testing project. I added the reference to the Communication project I created. There are 10 classes in the library but Visual Studio can only find 3 of them. I have built and rebuilt the solution, I have built and rebuilt the projects.  I have removed and re-added the reference. I have no idea where to go from here. I can't find anything online about this problem. I am not very familiar with Visual Studio and C# so I may just be searching the wrong things, but it is driving me nuts.

Here is the unit testing class, you can see that it is only finding three classes.

[image]
Here is a screen shot of the solution explorer showing the 10 classes that should be there (I'm trying to reference the Communication project), it also shows the reference:
[image]

And here is a picture of one of the classes so you can see it has the correct namespace:

[image]

I am going nuts here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stupid question - are missing classes `public` or `private`?

Comment: They are all whatever the default is. I dont work in c# much but I think they all default to private right?

Comment: Wait... now that I look at it. Some are set to public and it happens to be the three that it can find...

Comment: Default is `private`, and such classes are not visible outside if the project. Add keyword `public` to the definition, same as on `Envelop` class you show on the screenshot.

Comment: Looks like all the other classes are internal or private("private" is the default modifier, so if you type `class XYZ` it implicitly means `private class XYZ`. To view all the classes outside of that assembly/project, you'll have to make them all public.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks guys. I am not used to such formal languages.

Comment: @dmay @EvilTrak Technically, the default is `internal`, not `private` which is an invalid type visibility attribute. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).